# jQuery instant search

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jquery pluggin that allows me to have a user type into a text input and a drop down menu of options appear below. Ideally, these options would be passed in through a JSON object.

Comment: What is the relationship between the text input and the drop down menu?

Comment: [http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: @tskuzzy I'm looking for something like a google instant search where the user enters some text and matching text options drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin fit your needs.